# bitrix как получить ID пользователя зная его e-mail?

Tags: битрикс

bitrix  как получить ID пользователя зная его e-mail?

Answer (score 1):

```
//d7
use Bitrix\Main\UserTable;

$user = UserTable::getList([
    'select' => [
        'ID'
    ],
    'filter' => [
        'EMAIL' => 'user@mail'
    ]
])->fetch();

echo $user['ID'];

//old
$cUser = $USER::GetList(
    $by="ID",
    $order="desc",
    [
        'EMAIL' => 'user@mail'
    ],
    [
        'SELECT' => [
            'ID'
        ]
    ]
)->fetch();

echo $cUser['ID'];
```

Более подробно о работе приведенных методов вы можете посмотреть в [документации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cuser/getlist.php)